# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i got error Duplicate entry '19-0' for key 'PRIMARY' after insert all multiple to database

```
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$gorong = json_decode($resp);
foreach ($gorong->data as $g){
                        $this->db->insert('mod_auto_harga', array(
                        'sv_id' => '19',
                        'kode' => $g->buyer_sku_code,
                        'keterangan' => $g->product_name,
                        'harga' => $g->price,
                        'status' => $g->seller_product_status,
                        'type' => $g->type,
                        ));
     
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is your `sv_id` act as `PRIMARY KEY`, which acts as **unique**. It seems you misunderstood the purpose of PRIMARY KEY and `sv_id`.

To overcome this

1. Add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` `ID` field.
2. Remove exiting `PRIMARY KEY` constant from `sv_id.`

---

**To remove existing primary key**

```
ALTER TABLE mod_auto_harga MODIFY sv_id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE mod_auto_harga DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

**To add the new field as the primary key**

```
ALTER TABLE mod_auto_harga ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

---

> In addition, when inserting data into the table, don't fill the value to the `id` field, which will auto-increment by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the existing **sv_id** from that table and make a new **sv_id** attribute or column with an autoincrement option

```
AUTO_INCREMENT
PRIMARY KEY
```

You have made a mistake in existing column, you didn't set the property auto increment.
Just go to localhost or anywhere at live server and use the above idea for resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

You set column sv_id as primary key on database.  but hardcoded it on insert as 19. remove that column, it should be auto generated on insert.

If you do need all those to have 19 as value. Then from database remove that indexing from that column. and add a new column for primary key.